# Vite, React + TS выдает тонну странных ошибок тайпскрипта

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

Ставил все так:

```
> npm create vite@latest
> .
> react
> typescript
```

Получаю тонну таких вот ошибок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а если сменить `FC` на `React.FC`, то пропсы хедера вообще станут `any`, не смотря на прописаный интерфейс => тс не ругается на то, что я делаю что то такое, хоть по идее и должен
`<Header userName={69} />`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я тайпскрипт учить только начинаю и в конфиги не лез. Делал все +- как в уроках на ютубе, только в результате получил кучу ошибок линтера (которых, по идее быть не должно)

В чем у меня проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в конфигах

`"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // добавил`

`"moduleResolution": "node" // а было "bundler",`

Вообще не понял, почему так, но да ладно